# Cousin Problem - Hypersurface is defined by holomorphic function

Tags: geometry, complex-geometry

how do I show that any hypersurface $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ is the
defined by a global holomorphic function $f: \mathbb{C}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$?

This is an exercise from Daniel Huybrechts' "Complex Geometry: An Introduction" and there the exercise says one should use the Poincaré lemma to prove this statement.

Comment: You mean $D = \{ z,f(z)=0\}$, you can recover $f$ from a chart $\phi: U\subset \Bbb{C}^{n-1} \to D$ by looking at the kernel of $g \mapsto g\circ \phi$ for $g$ in the ring of functions holomorphic  around $\phi(D)$

Comment: @reuns and where do I use the Poincaré lemma here?

Comment: Hint:$D\subset\mathbb C^n$ is a domain of holomorphy $\iff  H^{p,q}(D)=0$ for $p>0$ or $q>0$.